Divide groups in other groups by date intervals
I'm dealing with dates and I wanted to group some rows together but I can't find how.
In my data, one row is an individual in a time interval and in a place. Something like that :
     ind place start_date end_date  
   <int> <int> <date>     <date>    
 1     1     1 2011-01-04 2011-01-05
 2     1     1 2011-01-05 2011-01-06
 3     1     1 2011-01-10 2011-01-11
 4     1     4 2010-12-30 2010-12-31
 5     1     4 2010-12-31 2011-01-01
 6     1     4 2011-01-01 2011-01-03
 7     2     2 2018-02-17 2018-02-19
 8     2     2 2018-02-19 2018-02-23
 9     3     3 2018-02-08 2018-02-13
10     3     3 2018-02-13 2018-02-16
11     3     3 2018-02-16 2018-02-20
12     3     3 2018-03-27 2018-03-29

As you can see, sometimes, start_date is the same as in previous end_date. I can group_by ind and place in order to merge time intervals, but the problem is that there are some rows where there is a gap between start_date and previous end_date. So I need to divide these groups in multiple other groups before merging.
What I want to obtain first is :
     ind place start_date end_date   group
   <int> <int> <date>     <date>     <int>
 1     1     1 2011-01-04 2011-01-05   1
 2     1     1 2011-01-05 2011-01-06   1
 3     1     1 2011-01-10 2011-01-11   2
 4     1     4 2010-12-30 2010-12-31   3
 5     1     4 2010-12-31 2011-01-01   3
 6     1     4 2011-01-01 2011-01-03   3
 7     2     2 2018-02-17 2018-02-19   4
 8     2     2 2018-02-19 2018-02-23   4
 9     3     3 2018-02-08 2018-02-13   5
10     3     3 2018-02-13 2018-02-16   5
11     3     3 2018-02-16 2018-02-20   5
12     3     3 2018-03-27 2018-03-29   6


And at the end :
     ind place start_date end_date  
    <chr> <chr> <date>     <date>    
 1     1     1 2011-01-04 2011-01-06
 2     1     1 2011-01-10 2011-01-11
 3     1     4 2010-12-30 2011-01-03
 4     2     2 2018-02-17 2018-02-23
 5     3     3 2018-02-08 2018-02-20
 6     3     3 2018-03-27 2018-03-29

Do you have an idea of how can I do it ?
Thanks !

One way is to add an additional grouping variable that checks if end_date is less then start_date
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(end_date, default=end_date[1]) < start_date),
           ind, place) %>% 
  summarize(start_date = first(start_date), 
            end_date = last(end_date), .groups="drop") %>% 
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 6 × 4
    ind place start_date end_date  
  <int> <int> <date>     <date>    
1     1     1 2011-01-04 2011-01-06
2     1     1 2011-01-10 2011-01-11
3     1     4 2010-12-30 2011-01-03
4     2     2 2018-02-17 2018-02-23
5     3     3 2018-02-08 2018-02-20
6     3     3 2018-03-27 2018-03-29


Maybe with max and min and not first and last

@jrdavalos If the data is ordered (seems like it is) that should give the same results. (min and max do return Inf in case there are empty groups, this is sometimes undesired)

First you can sort arrange by the start date, then create a grouping column where the start differs from the previous row's end. The final start and end will be the min and max dates within these groups.
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(start = as.Date(start_date), end = as.Date(end_date)) %>%
  arrange(ind, place, start) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(coalesce(start != lag(end), 0)), .by = c(ind, place)) %>%
  reframe(start = min(start), end = max(end), .by = c(ind, group, place)) %>% 
  select(-group) %>%
  arrange(ind, place)

Output
  ind place      start        end
1   1     1 2011-01-04 2011-01-06
2   1     1 2011-01-10 2011-01-11
3   1     4 2010-12-30 2011-01-03
4   2     2 2018-02-17 2018-02-23
5   3     3 2018-02-08 2018-02-20
6   3     3 2018-03-27 2018-03-29

